# How do i get the parent value of fetched firebase data?

Tags: java, android

Here i fetch the data from firebase database and set in recylerview.
Its is succesfully run , but i need the value of parent for the new intent
i used this types code.

I need a key of each binded laout in recyclerview.
But the problem is whenver i used getAdapterPosition(i), it returns value, its ok. but i need its actual value.

```
public class AllPostAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AllPostAdapter.AllPostViewHolder>
{

    }

@NonNull
@Override
public AllPostViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i)
{

    View view=LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.all_post_layout,viewGroup,false);
    AllPostViewHolder viewHolder=new AllPostViewHolder(view);
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull AllPostViewHolder allPostViewHolder, int i)

{


//Here i need the parent actual value not like 0,1,2,3...//
holder.name.setText(Post.get(i).getName());

holder.email.setText(Post.get(i).getEmail());
    }

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return postArrayList.size();
}
```

Comment: Your question does not provide full information and clear question. Can you please provide more details and specify clearly your question?

Comment: It Is a clear question. which content didnt you get ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you mean you need to get the firebase realtime database items unique key. First of all from where you are fetching the code you need to get the key like this.

```
     @Override
public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildName) {

    Comment newPost = dataSnapshot.getValue(Post.class);
    String postKey = dataSnapshot.getKey();
    newPost.setKey(postKey)
}
```

Then in the recyclerview adapter you can get the key and call the intent passing that key like this.

```
    @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull AllPostViewHolder allPostViewHolder, int i)
{
    Post post = postArrayList.get(i)
    holder.name.setText(post.getName());
    holder.email.setText(post.getEmail());
    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context , YourIntent.class);
            intent.putExtra("Key" , post.getKey());
            holder.itemView.getContext().startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```